# Why does app crash on iOS 14 when setting UIDatePicker preferredDatePickerStyle

Tags: ios, crash, uidatepicker

**The problem:**

- User reports iOS crashes when calling `datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = ...` in Swift or `[self.datePicker setPreferredDatePickerStyle:UIDatePickerStyleInline]` in Objective-C
- The app is available from iOS 12+ but this code is only called in iOS 14+
- I was not able to reproduce the issue on any device or in simulator
- No other users reported the same problem

---

**Details:**

A user of my iOS 12+ reported that the app crashes after the update when using different features. The user send me multiple crash reports and I was able to symbolicate them using Xcode. The reports show, that the crash occurs in two different view controllers but in the same situation: When setting the `preferredDatePickerStyle` of `UIDatePicker`.

One view controller uses Objective-C while the other is newer and uses swift:

```
// Swift
class MyViewControllerA {
    @IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    ...
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline   // << CRASH
        }
        ...
    }
}


// Objective-C
@interface MyViewControllerB : UIViewController
    ...
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@end

...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    ... 

    if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
        [self.datePicker setPreferredDatePickerStyle:UIDatePickerStyleInline];  // << CRASH
    }  
}
```

`preferredDatePickerStyle` is available since iOS 13.4+, thus calling it with `if (@available(iOS 14, *))` should be not problem, should it?

I cannot see anything problematic at these lines. There is no reason why `datePicker` should be `nil` in the Swift VC and if it would be `nil` in the Objective-C version it would be no problem, would it?

**There are no reports by other users and I was not able to reproduce the issue in several test. Everything works just as expected.**

---

**Crash Reports:**

These are the device details from the crash reports:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,6
Process:             MyApp [12455]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/UUID/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.example.MyApp
Version:             3.0.2.1 (3.0.2)
AppStoreTools:       12D4d
AppVariant:          1:iPhone10,6:13
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.example.MyApp [910]

Date/Time:           2021-02-18 15:00:30.0155 +0200
Launch Time:         2021-02-18 15:00:24.0409 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.4 (18D52)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.02.01
Report Version:      104
```

Crash Report in Objective-C VC:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18b3999d8 0x18b27f000 + 1157592
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19f71fb54 0x19f719000 + 27476
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18b2a850c 0x18b27f000 + 169228
3   Foundation                      0x18c5a2878 0x18c52b000 + 489592
4   UIKitCore                       0x18e1160f0 0x18d0d6000 + 17039600
5   UIKitCore                       0x18d7716f4 0x18d0d6000 + 6928116
6   UIKitCore                       0x18d8524f4 0x18d0d6000 + 7849204
7   UIKitCore                       0x18d84fad0 0x18d0d6000 + 7838416
8   UIKitCore                       0x18d850fe4 0x18d0d6000 + 7843812
9   UIKitCore                       0x18d851224 0x18d0d6000 + 7844388
10  UIKitCore                       0x18d17b938 0x18d0d6000 + 678200
11  UIKitCore                       0x18d17bcd8 0x18d0d6000 + 679128
12  UIKitCore                       0x18d17d354 0x18d0d6000 + 684884
13  UIKitCore                       0x18db77584 0x18d0d6000 + 11146628
14  UIKitCore                       0x18db7a1f8 0x18d0d6000 + 11158008
15  MyApp                           0x102b51d94 -[DatePickerViewController viewDidLoad] + 712084 (DatePickerViewController.m:88)
16  UIKitCore                       0x18d53ee50 0x18d0d6000 + 4623952
17  UIKitCore                       0x18d543408 0x18d0d6000 + 4641800
18  UIKitCore                       0x18d5437e8 0x18d0d6000 + 4642792
```

Crash Report in Swift VC

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18b3999d8 0x18b27f000 + 1157592
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19f71fb54 0x19f719000 + 27476
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18b2a850c 0x18b27f000 + 169228
3   Foundation                      0x18c5a2878 0x18c52b000 + 489592
4   UIKitCore                       0x18e1160f0 0x18d0d6000 + 17039600
5   UIKitCore                       0x18d7716f4 0x18d0d6000 + 6928116
6   UIKitCore                       0x18d8524f4 0x18d0d6000 + 7849204
7   UIKitCore                       0x18d84fad0 0x18d0d6000 + 7838416
8   UIKitCore                       0x18d850fe4 0x18d0d6000 + 7843812
9   UIKitCore                       0x18d851224 0x18d0d6000 + 7844388
10  UIKitCore                       0x18d17b938 0x18d0d6000 + 678200
11  UIKitCore                       0x18d17bcd8 0x18d0d6000 + 679128
12  UIKitCore                       0x18d17d354 0x18d0d6000 + 684884
13  UIKitCore                       0x18db77584 0x18d0d6000 + 11146628
14  UIKitCore                       0x18db7a1f8 0x18d0d6000 + 11158008
15  MyApp                           0x104345ce8 EditPageViewController.viewDidLoad() + 2284776 (ContractEditPageViewController.swift:107)
16  MyApp                           0x104345fdc @objc EditPageViewController.viewDidLoad() + 2285532 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  UIKitCore                       0x18d53ee50 0x18d0d6000 + 4623952
18  UIKitCore                       0x18d543408 0x18d0d6000 + 4641800
```

**Any idea how to find out what is going wrong?**